# Как организовать проверку присутствия пользователя в комнате на мобильном приложении?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript

Как лучше проверить в мобильном приложении Nativescript, что пользователь рядом?
Планирую поставить планшет, где приложение будет отображать информацию, когда пользователь рядом.
Но если пользователя в комнате нет- хотелось бы через некоторое время выключить экран, а когда он зайдёт- включить экран.
Как лучше организовать проверку, что пользователь рядом?
Прослушку микрофона, камеры или как это вообще делается, что б пользователь не нажимал никаких кнопок и приложение включалось?

Comment: Объёмный датчик да контроллер к нему... и лови сигнал. Микрофон да камера (без распознавания силуэтов) ничего не даст - если юзер спит, но не храпит, то его как бы и нет...

Comment: @Akina то-есть купить систему умный дом с датчиком движения и привязать её к системе?

Comment: Вообще нет... объёмный не подойдёт, он детектит не факт, а изменение. Так что нужно что-то типа емкостного датчика.